# how to create logic app with standard plan using powershell

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-powershell

I am not able to create a logic app from PowerShell with standard mode, I can be able to create consumption plan logic App. Also when I fetch logic apps under my resource group with command Get-AzResource, its only displaying logic apps with consumption plan,

Comment: AFAIK, No it is not possible, community can provide on creating standard logic app using on arm or bicep deployment

Answer (score 0):

> How to create logic app with standard plan using PowerShell:

Azure PowerShell is not currently supported for Standard logic app processes running in single-tenant Azure Logic Apps. However, [New-AzLogicapp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.logicapp/new-azlogicapp?view=azps-10.1.0) command is used to create a logic app with the consumption plan as you already knew it.

Concerning the other issue you are dealing with,

> PowerShell command Get-AzResource, its only displaying logic apps with consumption plan:

I created a new logic app with consumption plan from Portal and tried retrieving that in the below manner.

[image]

```
Get-Azresource -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites -ResourceGroupName "<resourcegroup>"
```

I was able to obtain the standard plan logic apps too as shown.

[image]